# Will having two Xbox 360 consoles mean any unforeseen consequences?

Tags: xbox-360

I have an Xbox 360 with a broken dvd drive and a packed hdd. So now I want to buy a new one, to play disc games. But I figure "why not keep the old console also"?

So am I right in assuming the following?

- What I need to do is transfer my profile (and any savegame files) to the new console with a usb stick.
- I can then keep playing as [my account] on both consoles.
- However, I cannot use them both at the same time.
- There are no other drawbacks to this?

Comment: From what I understand, there _are_ ways to transfer/install new disc drives (both hdd and optical).  Doing so would void your warranty... but you can find parts on ebay.  Would this be an option?

Comment: I thought on that for a while earlier, but decided it would probably end up costing a sizeable portion of the cost for a new console, and would end up sucking titanicly in case something else broke later on.

Comment: I recommend you go and buy a transfer cable from GameStop, copy all your data to the working console, then return the cable when you are done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've regularly been using my Xbox Live account on 3 different consoles. If I remember correctly I didn't use a USB drive, instead I just retrieved the account from the magic of the internet. I'm not sure about what @TZHX means when they say that you'll have to re-download your account every time you switch, if he is right about that it's not something that you actually have to do, as the Xbox will do it for you. The only thing I've noticed is that when I sign on to a different console, a message pops up that says "This profile was last used on a different console."

The only downside that I can think of at the moment is that if you get achievements while offline on one console and go online with the second, those achievements may be lost. So all in all yes, you are correct it is possible and the Xbox makes it really easy for you.

Comment: That sounds great. I usually don't ever play offline. But maybe if my son wants to play while I do, I can let him play his games offline and thus use both consoles at the same time?

Comment: If that's something that you want to do I would suggest making another account for your son. It's free, and he would probably love having his own.

Comment: I'd consider that. I'm not gonna pay for gold for another account though :)

Comment: Oh, you wouldn't need to. All of my Xboxes have had a "guest" account, you don't need to buy them gold. Plus I think you can set parental controls on it too.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're largely correct -- the main thing I'd mention is that copying the profile to a new console, when you use it, it will invalidate the copy on the old console, forcing you to re-download (or "sync") it when you next connect to Xbox Live.

You can get around this by simply keeping your profile on a USB stick that you move between consoles with you.

As an additional note, having two consoles means having two power bricks, using up twice the amount of space under your TV and a second HDMI port and power outlet. If you use a Wireless controller it will mean re-syncing it each time you change between the two, if you use a wired controller it means unplugging it every time you switch.

Comment: Thanks. I will want to keep one of them in my son's room, but moving controllers back and forth might become a problem. Having the profile on a usb stick sounds like a pain. But so does syncing. Am I right in understanding that every time I use the one I didn't use last time, I will have to do this? Does it take time? Are there risks involved? Does it require manual input?

Comment: You can download your profile to as many consoles as you want, wilk not invalidate the other profile. The old console will keep the games and such unless you re-register everything to the new console. All games you own will work with your profile online. Leaving everything on the broken console will ensure your son has games to play on it. Also, using media player you can share all your movies to his room if it's connected to the router.

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly triggers having to re-download your account. I've had it happen before, but I'm not sure it's *every* time.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**, if you are connecting both to the internet on the same router then you will likely run into NAT type issues. Even connecting a single system can have these issues because they are Microsoft / Whoever Built Your Router compatibility issues.

In the past I have tried Microsoft's support number and they walked me through opening ports and a bunch of other nonsense to get both my Xbox and my roommate's Xbox working with at least one of us having Open NAT type, however it was never possible for them to get us both Open NAT with at least one of us always being stuck on Moderate or Strict. They said the only solution was to use a different router for each system.

However since you are likely using a single login and one cannot login to two identical systems at once this might not affect you, unless you have both of them on at the same time when you switch systems. Once you turn them on they sort of "lock in" their connection settings. In the example above, whichever of us turned on our system first would "keep" the Open NAT type until we had BOTH switched off our systems. Even if I got it first, he turned his on, and I turned mine off, his would remain on Moderate unless he restarted too.

Basically whichever one you want to have a better connection on, turn that one on first. Or not worry about it by only using the older system as an offline only setup. :)